# Show color in gutter for commented CSS code in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm expecting below code to show color in gutter for commented CSS code.

```
/*
Light green: #7ed56f
*/
body {
    color: #7ed56f;
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Why? It's a comment -- a plain text. It is not getting checked for CSS syntax. 2) The commented fragment is not CSS. I do not remember seeing CSS properties named `Light green:`...

Comment: @LazyOne Ok. Then maybe any way to highlight `#7ed56f` part of commented code?

Comment: I'm not aware of such functionality in WebStorm. You can check here existing tickets on the "gutter color" subject ( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=gutter%20color ) and file a new Feature Request ticket if none matches your requirements. If you do that -- please post a ticket number/link back here. Potentially this could be implemented for such `#rgb` alike patterns (as it can easily be matched using regular expression)

Comment: Hey! Feel free to vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36759.